# How can I tell jquery to html( ) an element to its original value, before it was dynamically changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div, and I used `html()` to change its content. I am doing a "cancel" button, and I would like to `html()` back to the original value.

Is there an efficient way to do this? I'm trying to avoid to html() the whole code again, as it doesn't look very good and is probably not the best practice.

Thanks a lot in advance. Regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// store the old content
var myOldContent = $("#cancelbutton").html();

// change content
$("#cancelbutton").html(someNewContent);

// and change it back
$("#cancelbutton").html(myOldContent);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I tried your way but the jquery code that was working for myOldContent doesn't work anymore when I put that myOldContent back through `html`. Is there a specific reason why? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, `.html()` removes all events associated with an element. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874193/does-jquerys-html-remove-all-data-attached-to-elements-that-are-replaced

Comment: oh ok thanks a lot. I am reading through that to see what I can do. Regards

Comment: You may be interested in the `.live()` function for your events. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If at all possible, don't use `.html` to toggle content this way -- use two adjacent, nearly-identical elements, one with the old HTML and one with the new, and create a `hidden` CSS class with `display: none` and assign it to the second element. Then toggle this `hidden` class on both elements at the same time.

HTML:

```
<button class="cancel" id="cancel-original">Cancel</button>
<button class="cancel hidden" id="cancel-second">Cancelling...</button>
```

CSS:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$('button.cancel').click(function() {
    $('button.cancel').toggleClass('hidden'); // toggles both at once
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e9eLP/

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your response. Why shouldn't I use html? For resource reason or security? Thanks a lot

Comment: if you use html you might want to parse and validate the input

Comment: What I noticed is that the jquery (with the input validation) that worked in the original form, doesn't work in the same form that I html()'ed back. Trying to figure out why..

Comment: @alexx0186 There's always a risk of another JavaScript function changing the data your stored. But mostly, it's just cleaner -- your HTML document now has all the HTML right where another developer would expect it, the `hidden` class clearly indicates which one is going to be visible, and your JavaScript is as short and simple as possible.

Comment: Also, this trick keeps your JavaScript events on the elements from disappearing -- since the elements never actually are removed, just hidden from view.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone it when it's made, using jQuery, and when you cancel, delete that and clone the old version back in.

Answer (score 1):

The browser does not track the original value.
However, you can store the original HTML yourself into a variable when the page loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can save the previous HTML content into a variable and then restore from that variable on cancel.

```
var previousHtml = $('#someElement').html();
```

Then

```
$('#someElement').html(previousHtml);
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to save it in a variable before changing it:

```
<script>
var origHTML = $("#divid").html();
function ResetDiv(){
  $("#divid").html(origHTML);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

By using [jQuery's data() function](http://api.jquery.com/data/) you can easily hold the original value internally, and then restore it with something like this:

```
$('#a').click(function(){
    $('div').data('store',$('div').html()).html('foo');
});​​
$('#b').click(function(){
    $('div').html($('div').data('store'));
});
​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V8L4C/)**.
(Note that this example is just to illustrate how to store a value using data() and not meant for production code.)